# file_get_contents will not output in my error handler script

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-exists

I have a strange problem with regards to a custom error handler function that deals with fatal errors. The error on my website is an "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" - which of course I will fix. But I want a custom error page to show if it happens again.

The following code echo's number 1, but not my "error-page.php" and does not echo number 2. So it feels like the script is erroring on the file_get_contents line - but it's not telling me why.

To make matters worse - it echo's fine on my development server! But I cannot think of a set up difference that would effect this.

To try and solve this I have echo'd out the full path for the file_get_contents and it is correct - and file_exists returns true - so I am utterly stumped!

Worth noting - error-page.php is just a static HTML page so no offending code in that! It won't even file_get_contents a test.txt.

```
error_reporting(-1);

set_error_handler("customErrorPage");


register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');

function shutdownFunction()
{

    $last_error = error_get_last();

    if ($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
        fatalErrorHandler(E_ERROR, $last_error['message'], $last_error['file'], $last_error['line'], "");
    }
}

function fatalErrorHandler($error_level,$error_message,$error_file,$error_line,$error_context) {


    http_response_code(500);    


    $errorEmail = "<strong>Error on page:</strong> http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "<br />\n";
    $errorEmail .= "<strong>Message:</strong> " . $error_message . "<br />\n";
    $errorEmail .= "<strong>IP:</strong> " . getRealIpAddr() . "<br />\n";
    $errorEmail .= "<strong>Line:</strong> " . $error_line . "<br />\n";
    $errorEmail .= "<strong>File:</strong> " . $error_file . "<br />\n";


    if ((strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], ".com") > 0)) {


        $to = "james@email.com";
        $subject = "FATAL Error on " . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . " - " . $error_message;
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0'" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . WEBSITE_COMPANY . " <errors@" . WEBSITE_DOMAIN . ">" . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $errorEmail, $headers);

        echo "1";
        echo file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "includes/error-page.php");
        echo "2";
        die;

    } else {
        echo $errorEmail;
        die;
    }
}
```

This is what I see on my screen when running the script:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 14907 bytes) in
>   /home/sure-wise/htdocs/objects/myaccount.php on line 2666 1

Comment: `set_error_handler("customErrorPage");` - where is `customErrorPage` …?

Comment: It's almost identical to fatalErrorHandler and works for errors such as Division by zero/

Comment: _“This is what I see on my screen”_ - please also check the actual HTML code your browser received from the server. What do you see in there, after the “1” …?

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14907 bytes) in <b>/home/website/htdocs/objects/myaccount.php</b> on line <b>2666</b><br />